# Is it necessary to close a previous Redis connection, that was followed by a pipeline?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a function that may or may not do multiple Redis queries.

Some of these queries need values returned from previous queries, so they are made without a pipeline:

```
if action == "comments":
    if redis_connection.exists(key) == 0:
        increment = Comments.objects.filter(user__uuid=uuid).count()
    redis_connection.incrby(f"{uuid}_{comment_uuid}, increment)
```

While others may be called multiple times inside the function in a for loop, requiring a pipeline to optimize it:

```
    if redis_connection.exists(user_comment_key) == 0:
        reactions = CommentReactions.objects.filter(comment__uuid=comment_uuid, user__uuid=user_uuid)
    for reaction in reactions:
        with redis_connection.pipeline() as pipe:
            pipe.sadd(user_comment_key, reaction)
```

This pipeline call is where I got confused. Since I'm calling it inside a context manager (with), will all other connections also be closed, or should I close every other single connection separately?